# Pretty URL with PHP and file name as argument

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have this nginx configuration, trying to rewrite **mysite.com/user/1234** to **mysite.com/user.php?id=1234**. However, I get 404 error. What's wrong in my code?

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name [[MYSITE]];


       location / {
                rewrite ^/user/(.*)$ /user.php?id=$1 last;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless;
        }


        location @extensionless {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
        }


        [...]
```

Comment: I don't see any [fastcgi](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) directives in the config you posted above. Is this somewhere else?

Comment: @FaisalMemon it's there under the same *server* block, added that part now.

Comment: Can you post the actual 404 error you are seeing from the NGINX access log?